# Honeycomb fragments vs AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-3.0-honeycomb

I would like to create a fragment for android honeycomb.
I used to build the gui from the xml (some labels and two list view) , however i must to download data from API so i needed an asynctask. I start the download process in `onActivityCreated` method. The downloading working well, but the listviews won`t be updated.

How I tried:
In the asynctask callback I used

```
getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(fragment_layout.xml)
```

then I used the `findViewById` for the listview. After building the adapter I used `listView.setAdapter()` method. This way has worked in not tablet android, I mean OS <2.3

Somebody have any idea how to refresh the listview in the fragment?

PS: in the `onCreateView` i just inflated the `fragment_layout.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Just call `setListAdapter()` on your `ListFragment` when the data is ready, in `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Awesome, +1! Totally worked for me, thank you! I've experimented with notifyDataSetChanged but that didn't work.